# where to add queries ? in a model or a controller in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am working on a Cakephp 2.x.. i have watched many tutorials and read documentation too ... but i didnt get one thing .. i have seen that in some tutorials they write queries in a model and some of them write every thing in controller and model remains clean except they add validation rules etc ... how i am coding right now is like that

```
   class ContactsController extends AppController{

  public function index(){
    $this->layout='default';

    $id = $this->Auth->user('idUser');
    $data= $this->Contact->find('all',array(
        'conditions' => array('Contact.User_id' => $id)));
    $this->set('contacts',$data);

}
```

}

I wrote the **find** function here in controller..i have seen in some tutorials they have written this in **model** class and then call it in Controller .. so i want to ask what would be the best way or what is actually the standard way ? should i have to code everything in controller and write just validation rules in model ? how should i code so that my code looks clean and easily manageable

Comment: [this is a good article](http://bitfluxx.com/2008/01/23/cakephp-best-practices-fat-models-and-skinny-controllers.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with Arkheart. I think you should put it in the model. Your model then becomes essentially a data API for your controllers. You have much cleaner separation of concerns. And to what downside? Your models will have more methods in them. So what.

Comment: well now i am confused ... dont know what to do ... actually i want it to be in model .. but in most tutorials they have written everything in controllers

Comment: Because most tutorials are poorly written. ;) You better use the official documentation.

Answer (score 3):

There are several reasons why you want to do queries in a model:

- Data manipulation and fetching is a clear model task in the MVC pattern
- You can not re-use queries if done in a controller, simple example is that you want to do something from a shell AND a controller.
- Models are a lot easier to unit test than controllers
- If you need to change a query you do it in ONE model, not 10 controllers that might do the same query or method.

For an example check the view() method of the controller and model here

- Controller https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/master/Controller/UsersController.php#L218
- Model: https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/master/Model/User.php#L536

Same for other methods. Just check how much code is in the model and how much in the controller and try to get an understanding why.

What others stated here is wrong: It is clearly *no* standard to do queries in the controller.